# Excel: Prevent mm:ss format data being interpreted as HH:mm

Tags: excel, time, format

I have a column of data in the form mm:ss (minutes, seconds) which I want to copy into Excel, but Excel interprets this as HH:mm which means any times over 24 minutes are represented as DD/MM/YYYY  HH:mm in Time format.

Presumably there's an easy way to tell Excel the correct format of the data you're importing but I don't know what it is. Can anyone help?

Comment: quick fix, not correct, but quick, format the cells `[hh]:mm:ss`  Longer fix is to have the data that being imported changed to add the `00:` for hours.  After that it is a matter of writing code that divides the time by 60 to get the correct time reference.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the column / cells in question
2. Right-click on it and then click on "Format cells" or "Format"
3. Choose "Text" so that the content is not formatted and displayed as it is

More details:

- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/264372/how-to-control-and-understand-settings-in-the-format-cells-dialog-box
- https://support.office.com/en-us/article/video-format-numbers-in-cells-e6656c9b-a36a-4143-8fe4-5b6de0d9486b

Hope it helps :)

Comment: If this is done after the import the cells will show a number as a decimal.  The format to Text will need to take place during the import using the import wizard, or Excel will make the change automatically.

Comment: For example type `55:25` into a cell, then format it as Text.  You will show `2.309027778` in the cell. As that is how Excel stores Date/Time.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that the question was related to data import.

Comment: @ScottCraner So how do I format to text during the import? For context I'm importing table data from a website by copy/paste

Comment: @TJBox you need to format the column as text before copying then paste just the values.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a simple solution which works for me:
1. Paste in data. Excel will automatically assume it's hh:mm:ss
2. Divide each cell by 60 e.g. B1=(A1/60), B2=(A2/60) etc. Hours become minutes, minutes become seconds.

NB: this won't work if you have anything other than 0 in the milliseconds section, because obviously there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, not 60.